# Изображение на сайте. Зачем надо было вставлять внутрь тега A с background-image, тег img с display:none и псевдоэлемент before на эту ссылку?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, изображения

Пытаюсь в качестве обучения скопировать верстку сайта [iWebka.com](https://iwebka.com/)

Там есть скрины выполненных работ. Они задаются в теге `<a>` через `background-image` в атрибуте `style`. Непонятно, зачем внутри тега ссылки находится тег `<img>` с `display: none`? И зачем там применяется псевдоэлемент `::before`? Я через DevTools удалил тег `<img>`, поставил `display: none` для псевдоэлемента `::before`, но все осталось, как прежде. 
Какой был смысл в подобной разметке и стиле?

Для ссылки (класс `.image`) используется следующий псевдоэлемент:

```
.spotlights > section > .image:before {
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  background: rgba(49, 36, 80, 0.9);
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Я думаю, что я все равно не объясню все соответствующие стили тут, поэтому просто предлагаю вам посмотреть все на сайте через инструменты разработчика.

Comment: ::before - Там для анимации.  Используется вот так: .spotlights > section.inactive > .image:before, body.is-loading .spotlights > section > .image:before {
    opacity: 1;
}

Comment: Хорошо. А что с img?

Comment: Для красоты наверное )

Comment: Это заглушка, если отключить JavaScrit на сайте встают картинки на место ссылок <a> Можете отключить в браузере JavaScript-ы и убедится в этом лично.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вопрос №1 - "Зачем надо было вставлять внутрь тега A с background-image , тег img с display:none "

Ответ:  Захотели они так сделать наверное. На тег IMG свойство "display:none"  Присваивается средствами JS, дабы скрыть картинку и отобразить только BG с ссылки тег A.

> Вопрос №2 -"Зачем надо было вставлять псевдоэлемент before на эту ссылку?"

Ответ:  Псевдоэлемент before там для анимации которая срабатывает при движение скролла до блока с работой.

Код CSS:

```
.spotlights > section.inactive > .image:before, 
body.is-loading .spotlights > section > .image:before {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

**Вот так выглядит без JavaScript:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*Активен тег IMG*

**Вот так выглядит с JavaScript:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*Тег img скрыт, активен тег A*